# Delete a range of rows in MySQL --Not working

Tags: mysql, zabbix

Here is my MySQL command. It doesn't work as no rows are affected when in fact 1609 rows should be affected. I am not sure what is going on but I am frustrated. I can delete them on at a time but I don't have the patience to do that. Any ideas?

```
mysql> DELETE FROM triggers WHERE templateid between 24126 and 25757;
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: if you use a SELECT instead of DELETE do you see the rows you expect?

Comment: Also see this documentation on the where clause http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm and this on the use of between http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure if that's the problem, but, try this:

```
DELETE FROM triggers WHERE templateid > 24126 and templateid < 25757;
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` is actually `>=` and `<=` but otherwise the two statements should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it wasn't a problem. It was my problem. Sorry, everyone. I guess that is not a good way to start my membership.